# Google Map SDK Markers for IOS (Xcode)

Tags: ios, xcode, markers

So I am working in Xcode in order to build an app and need some help.
My simple question is, is there a way to add multiple markers to the Google Map  (in this case, the markers will be multiple bus stops on a route) without having to create a new var marker each time I want to create a new bus stop (marker). If so what is the best way to do this because I will need to add 20 bus stops. Hope my question makes sense. The sooner I know the answer to this question the better!

Comment: follow this :https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker for bus stop icon add image of that on marker.

Comment: With create new marker instance it is not possible you need to create new marker every time